# trying to clear all form fields using a hook function in React. Adding object to onClick event

Tags: reactjs, onclick, react-hooks

I have created the following hook in a small React project project.
import { useState } from "react";

```
export default initialValue => {
  const [name, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  const handleChange = e => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const reset = () => {
    setValue("");
  };
  return [name, reset, handleChange];
};
```

Now in my App.js I have imported the hook.  I have the following code that uses the hook to populate the form.

```
import React from "react";
import useInputHook from "../Hooks/useFormState";
function App() {
const [name, setName, resetName] = useInputHook("");
const [surname, setSurname, resetSurname] = useInputHook("");
const [email, setEmail, resetEmail] = useInputHook("");
```

This issue I am having is using the resetName, resetSurname and resetEmail on the onClick event.
to clear the form fields. I get the following `error /src/components/App.jsx: Unexpected token, expected "..." (41:35)`
Below is the code for the form.

```
return (
<div className="container">
  <h1>
    Hello {name} {email}
  </h1>
  <h2>{email}</h2>
  <input
    onChange={setName}
    type="text"
    placeholder="What's your name?"
    value={name}
  />
  <input
    onChange={setSurname}
    type="text"
    placeholder="What's your surname?"
    value={surname}
  />
  <input
    onChange={setEmail}
    type="text"
    placeholder="What's your email?"
    value={email}
  />
  <button onClick={resetName} {resetSurname} {resetEmail}>Submit</button>
  </div>
 );
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have exported as `[value, reset function, change handler]`

and imported as `[value, change handler, reset function]` (wrong order)

the reset button at the bottom should activate all reset function as well like this:

`<button onClick={()=>resetName();resetSurname();resetEmail();}>Submit</button>`

- if you are setting your functions like that in the button they would become a props for the button and not get executed  when onClick is firing.
  this is wrong: `<button onClick={resetName} {resetSurname} {resetEmail}>Submit</button>`

you can try make a reset array of functions or play with useEffect cleanup function.

happy reacting!

Comment: I am still getting the same error on the onClick event.

Comment: unfortunately I am getting this error ```×
SyntaxError
/src/components/App.jsx: Unexpected token, expected "}"```

Comment: It is because either you have a brackets misplaced or you still have that button tag with wrong syntax in the props, please add the full source code if you still get stuck

Comment: You have the full source code. This is how I have written the onClick event.

Comment: ```<button onClick={()=> resetName(); resetSurname(); resetEmail() }>Submit</button>```

Comment: you are missing a brackets here you go:
`<button onClick={() => {resetName(); resetSurname(); resetEmail() }}>Submit</button>`